# MySQL - Create a table for each new row created in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an access control type setting. I have two tables, "users" and "doors". The users table has some info such as unique ID, first and last name, and email address. The doors table has info such as the Door ID, name, IP address of the reader on the door, and whether it is an internal door or an external door.

I want a third table with one column called "user ID", but also a column for each Door ID in the Doors table (with values as a varchar length 20), and a row for each User ID in the Users table.

If this were static, I'd just go through the time of creating it myself. But this is dynamic. I'll be adding doors, and adding/removing/changing user IDs.

What would be the easiest way to keep all this info in sync? If it matters at all, I have several PHP scripts that interact with the table.

Comment: You probably should pick up a good book about MySQL. Preferably, something, that does not contain the word "and" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to overcome this by using PHP scripts to automate this functionality instead of having the database itself do it; that way I can have the database structured how I want it.

The scripts deal with all of the adding of the user's data and the door's data to the table.

So when I add a door, the script adds it in both the doors table (including all the columns in that table), then automatically adds it to the access control table (the one all the readers query). When I change (or delete) the door id (it may change because it's id is the MAC address of the reader), the script will change it in the access control table. Same sort of thing when I change the User's info. If the user id changes (it's partially based on the unique id of their access card which may change if their card changes), It's reflected in both the users table and the access control table.

So there's no longer any linkages between anything in the tables, all the changes are done individually to each of them by PHP. Only downside is that there is the potential for data to be mismatched if I edit the DB directly.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking too complex. Just create a third table 'userdoors' with two columns: 'userid' and 'doorid'. Create a unique index which combines these two columns.

Add a row for each user-door relationship. The userids will be repeated multiple times for each door, but that's fine.

Now you can simply check if a user has access to a door (I assume that's what you're doing) with "select userid from userdoors where userid = [userid] and doorid = [doorid]" If this query returns a result, the user has access.

That's called n:m relationship. You can read more about it at e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

You can also add more than the two columns like 'time' to save the time the user was granted this specific door or 'granted_by' to save user who granted this specific relationship.

Comment: This sounds promising. However, I need the ability to have information in there somewhere regarding time limits (all contained within a string, such as "0900-1100,1200-1400"). How would I do this?

Comment: If the time limits for a door are the same for every user store them in the doors table (= they belong to the door). If they differ between the users store them in the relationship table in a new column 'timelimit' (= they belong to the relationship).

Comment: They are per door, per user. So Joe might be able to open the office door from 0900-1500, but only be able to open the break room door from 1200-1300 (aka lunch)

Comment: Then store them in the relationship table. Here you can store another time limit for each of the user/door relations.

Comment: You made any progress?

Comment: sorry it took so long to reply. Yes I have, I have setup a database with three columns: User ID, Door ID, and Time Limit. Now I have it working but it looks pretty ugly because there's like 20+ doors. So I have the same user ID in there 20 times, one for each door. Originally I wanted it to be a row for each user and a column for each door because then User IDs wouldn't have to be repeated. If I needed to change a user ID, I would've needed to change one field instead of 20+. In each column would be a string representing time limits. For now it works, I may try to change it later.

Comment: But now I've got to figure out how to replicate this main DB to the local copy on each door reader.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate table for each user, what you need is a [crosslink table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to establish relationship between users and doors (it's called a [many-to-many relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).)

However, to answer your original question, that's what a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) does - it exeutes a chunk of SQL code upon certain operations (insert/update/delete) on a table.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to solve this on the database itself, by applying foreign key constraints.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html